# Keys.Down acts differently from other arrow keys?

Tags: c#, listview, scroll

I have created a listView and when the user clicks on one element and presses an up or down arrow key, the element should move there and the element should stay selected. It works perfectly for the up arrow key, but when I paste the SAME CODE under the switch "case Keys.Down", only the TOP element in the listView stays selected. It's very weird! I have also pasted the same code under Keys.Left and Keys.Right switches, and the code works perfectly there, but as soon as I change the switch to Keys.Down, only the top element stays selected. Does anyone have any idea why this would happen?

Comment: Post the relevant part of the code.

Comment: Yes please post the code, to me it sounds like you are not breaking out of the switch cases properly.

Comment: Please use the `{}` button to format the code properly..

Comment: Instead of copy pasting all the code, if all 4 cases use the same code then you can just `case Keys.Up: case Keys.Down: case Keys.Left: case Keys.Right: { ... }`

Comment: the code is not actually supposed to be the same. I just did this to figure out why the problem was occurring. I see now that if I just change the case from Keys.Up to Keys.Down, it works wrongly, and I don't know how this would happen or a way to go around it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you remove all your code? You've removed all the context from the question... I'll revert just so we can keep this question potentially answerable unless you have good reason to do so. _PLEASE_ mention why you did that in the future in the edit reason or here in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

The offset  should be different in the down case. You use same one ( -1 ). In the down it should be +1 like so :

```
newSpot = listOrderNames.IndexOf(listView.SelectedItems[0].Text) + 1;
index = listOrderNames.IndexOf(listView.SelectedItems[0].Text) + 1;
```

Also, you can write this a lot cleaner as

```
int offset = 0;
case Keys.Up:
    offset = -1; 
    break;
case Keys.Down:
    offset = 1;
    break;
if (listView.SelectedItems.Count > 0) 
{
    int newSpot = 0;
    int index = 0;
    if (listOrderNames.IndexOf(listView.SelectedItems[0].Text) == 0) 
    {
        reorder(0, true);
        newSpot = listOrderNames.Count + offset;
    }
    else 
    {
        newSpot = listOrderNames.IndexOf(listView.SelectedItems[0].Text) + offset;
        index = listOrderNames.IndexOf(listView.SelectedItems[0].Text) + offset;
        swap(listOrderNames.IndexOf(listView.SelectedItems[0].Text), newSpot);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < listView.Items.Count; i++) 
    {
        listView.Items[i].Selected = false;
    }
    listView.Items[newSpot].Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't solve my problem. the loop at the end which deselects all the listView Items and the line after it still do not occur when the down error is pressed.

Comment: Basically, the same code that is posted in or under the switch events works differently if i press the down arrow and I am trying to figure out why

Comment: You mean the event never fires? Thats a different problem than what you mentioned above where something happened but its the wrong thing.